# Laravel read table data by id

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

Error

> Trying to get property of non-object

I'm having a problem in my new project. I've tried this codes from the recent project before and it works, but it doesn't work on my new project.
The difference is: in my old project i used 'id' as the table's primary key, and in my new project i used 'productid' as the table's primary key.

It can read the specific item's id i chose.

I've tried to use Products::where('id', $id); but it won't work

Controller:

```
   public function showDetail($id)
        {
            $products = Products::find($id);
            return view('sectiondetail', ['products' => $products], compact('products'));
        }
```

View:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
<div class="productdetail">
    <div id="thumbnail">
        <img src="{{ $product -> productpicture }}">
    </div>
    <div id="productdescription">
        <div id="name">{{ $product -> productname }}</div> <br>
        <div>
            <b>Ingredients:</b> {{ $product -> productdescription }}
        </div> <br>
        <button class="sim-button button24">Book</button>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: `find()` returns a single object, not an array of objects. Your foreach is actually iterating through the product variables, not an array of products.

Comment: `Products::where('id', $id);` will get you nowhere since your PK is `productid`. Also missing a `->get()`.

Comment: edited @Alexander

Comment: @aynber thanks for the detailed information

Answer (score 10):

Add `$primaryKey` to the `Products` model:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'productid';
```

Then this query will get you a product by it's ID:

```
$product = Products::find($id);
```

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions):

> Eloquent will also assume that each table has a primary key column named id. You may define a protected `$primaryKey` property to override this convention

Then just use the object to get the data (no need to iterate over `$product`):

```
{{ $product->productname }}
```

Comment: that is not the answer, the problem is that he is using `find()` instead `get()`. Find only get 1 record and cant be used in a foreach.

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz OP's controller looks like he's trying to get just one product by its ID.

Comment: So he should avoid using foreach in this case

Comment: thanks you were right, i shouldn’t use foreach in it. it works thankyou @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz